# Setting up wireless connection b/w Parrot drone and GCS

Tags: ros, wireless, odroid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set up Odroid-U3 board with a WiFi module running ROS
I would like to maintain wireless contact with the drone from my computer

What command will enable me to do so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191356/setting-up-wireless-connection-b/w-parrot-drone-and-gcs/) by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Creating this contact is completely unrelated from ROS.

The drone hosts its own WiFi-Network, which you have to connect to. Once this is done, you should read the documentation from [here](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy). Also, have a look into this [tutorial](http://robohub.org/up-and-flying-with-the-ar-drone-and-ros-getting-started/). It might not be completly compatible with the current AR-Drone-Driver, but when you use the virtual machine everythink should work. Nonetheless, it is a great introduction to accessing and programming the drone with ROS.

Good Luck!

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-08-27**:
Hi Rabe

I am using the Parrot Drone with Pixhawk controller (PX4FMU + PX4IAOR) and that's the reason for using WiFi module with the drone

I believe $ssh command would do

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-09-01**:
Oh, my bad, I was assuming you were going to use the ROS-Package. AFAIK there should be a Telnet port open on the drone, I think it was port number 21.

**Comment by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on 2014-10-10**:
The drone doesn't use any of Parrot central unit, but only its frame, motors and ESC

I need to view the 3D map from the [Structure Sensor](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/occipital/structure-sensor-capture-the-world-in-3d?ref=nav_search)
connected with the ODROID-U3 board
How do I achieve it